# intent not working in lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

```
   Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   phoneIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
   phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
   phoneIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(phoneIntent);
```

I'm calling this through a service's method onStartCommand() in my application.Its working  for <5 versions.Can anyone tell the reason behind this.I'v gone through links which told to use explicit intent.How can i use explicit intent to make a call from my application.Thanks In Advance.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @tyczj I'm not getting any errors..